# Converting HSV to RGB fails in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, hsv

OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor) of `cvtColor()` does not give information about HSV to BGR conversion. It says that conversion from RGB to HSV for 16bit images is not supported.

I need to convert HSV images with more than 8bit per pixel (16bit or 32bit is fine) to RGB image. Below code gives runtime error.

```
cv::Mat hsv(10, 10, CV_16UC3, cv::Scalar(0)); // same in cv::Mat hsv(10, 10, CV_32F);
cv::Mat rgb(hsv.size(), hsv.type());
cv::cvtColor(hsv, rgb, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);
```

Here is the runtime error

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cv::ipp_cvtColor, file C:\InstalledPrograms\opencv_3.1\sources\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp`

Comment: What are the pixels in the `hsv` filled with? I don't see where you are assigning the pixel values

Comment: opencv assumes (default) HSV 's hue values to be in range 0..180 so maybe your uninitialized values are something bigger? If doc says 16 bit isnt supported, why do you try 16 bit?!? If you need something not-supported, maybe you can adjust opencv source code (it's open source! )!

Comment: @Micka Document says conversion from RGB to HSV is not supported for 16bit images, but it does not say anything about conversion from HSV to RGB. It also says that RGB to HSV conversion is supported for 32bit images but it also gives runtime error for HSV to RGB conversion for 32bit.

Comment: what error do you get? Maybe your values aren't in a proper HSV range?

Comment: @Micka Updated the question

Comment: @RickM. Added default value for `hsv`, error did not change.

Comment: this message tells you that you need 3 channels in input image and 3 or 4 channels in the output image, which is ok im your sample. But it further tells you, that only 8U and 32F depths are allowed atm. Switch to CV_32FC3 and tell us the new error message please.

Comment: @Micka `CV_32FC3` works fine, thank you. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Melike exactly what Micka says. Now that you assigned values and changed the type to be `CV_32FC3` or `CV_8UC3`, you shouldn't be getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `CV_32F` you have to use `CV_32FC3` because you need 3 channels.

According to your error message (in addition to the doc) for `CV_16UC3`, 16 bit is neither supported for RGB/BGR=>HSV nor for HSV=>RGB/BGR